# How to solve the following generalized quadratic programming problem

Tags: linear-programming, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

I want to solve a generalized form of a quadratic programming problem
$$\min_x \left(\sqrt{x^TPx}+\sqrt{x^TQx}\right)^2+c^Tx$$,
$$\textrm{ s.t. } Ax\le b.$$ Here, $P$ and $Q$ are both positive definite.

As you know, the ordinary quadratic programming only involves one positive definite matrix, i.e.
$$\min_x x^TQx+c^Tx$$ 
$$\textrm{s.t. } Ax\le b$$

Now I want to ask how to solve the first generalized form. Thank you so much.

Comment: Well its still convex, albeit non-smooth. Looks like primal-dual methods, alternating direction method of multipliers or so could be applied…

Comment: The problem is convex. Moreover, it can be transformed into a second cone problem, which means it can be solved very efficiently . Indeed one can write $x^T P x \le u^2$ and $x^T Q x \le v^2$ (which are both second-order cone constraints) and simply minimize $(u+v)^2+c^T x$, which is quadratic convex (and also second-order cone representable).